# express PUT shows cannot PUT error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this in my express

```
router.put('/admin/profile?:id/actions', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body.actions)
});
```

and in postman I do a PUT request

http://localhost:3000/api/admin/58fb442234c93715b435395/actions

with actions as key like

actions:approve

but I get cannot PUT error? I'm expecting 'approve' in my node's console.

Comment: Should the `profile?` be in your route?

Comment: "with actions as key like" — Don't tell us what it is like. Tell us what the body actually is.

Comment: What Content-Type request header are you sending from Postman?

Comment: What body parser settings have you configured in your express application?

Comment: "cannot PUT error" — What is the exact error message? What tool reports the error? Is it shown on the Node console? Is it show in the HTTP response? Is it generated internally by Postman?

Answer (score 1):

Your route might be wrong. As far as I understand the express.js documentation on route paths, as long as your `:id`-parameter does not start with either `profil` or `profile`, your route will not be called.

Remove the `profile?` from your path.

Answer (score -1):

try the following in postman as you are sending data in params so the name of action is requires as approve/disapprove

```
http://localhost:3000/api/admin/58fb442234c93715b435395/approve
```

if you want to send the key name as well so use query params 
like

```
http://localhost:3000/api/admin/58fb442234c93715b435395?action=approve

router.put('/admin/profile?:id/actions',
```

change your router.put to

```
router.put('/admin/profile/:id/:actions',
```

Comment: Nothing you put in the URL will ever show up in `req.body`